# How to assign value to variable from a string split in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want to assign the array item into variable directly using groovy like this:

```
def str = "xyz=abc"
def [name, value] = str.split("=")
```

but groovy doesn't like it. Is there a way to do that (not storing the array result and get the index[0], index[1] from it?).

Thanks,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need parenthesis instead of brackets:

```
def str = "xyz=abc"
def (name, value) = str.split("=")
```

[image]

Note that you'll need to know how many elements you're expecting or you'll have unexpected results.

Comment: what is the different between [] and ()? Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: while brackets are appropriate for arrays, the parenthesis are how Groovy does multiple assignment. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Multiple+Assignment

Answer (score 5):

```
def name, value
(name,value) = str.split("=")
```

You just need to do your definition before your multiple assignment.